# How can I use column values for SVG colors using JS/D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I searched for this and found a lot of info on how to set scales, but I'm trying to color individual SVGs created in D3 using values from a column that's populated with hex values.  In the code below "Color1" is the column populated with different hex color values, e.g., #000000;

Here's what I've tried that makes intuitive sense to me but isn't working, instead the chart populates with the fill as black:

```
  var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',function (d) { return xScale(d.xvalue) })
      .attr('cy',function (d) { return yScale(d.yvalue) })
      .attr('r','3')
      .attr('stroke','black')
      .attr('stroke-width',1)
      .attr('fill', function (d) {return d.Color1})
```

I've also tried surrounding the function with `"'"` but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Does the property include the `#`? And if you use `function(d) { console.log(d.Color1); return d.Color1)` what is logged?

Comment: On top of the comment above, it's a good practice using `style` instead of `attr` for things like fill, stroke, etc. Their result are both valid SVGs, but if you have a CSS somewhere it will override `attr`, but not `style`.

Comment: Andrew, yes, it includes # and ;.  Here's what's returned with console.log: `Color1: "#0C2340;"`
Gerardo, thanks for the tip and I'll use that going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color  property should not include a semicolon:

```js
var data = [
  {Color1: "#aaaaaa;"}, 
  {Color1: "#aaaaaa"}
]

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
   .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
      .attr('cx',(d,i)=>i*100+50)
      .attr('cy', 100)
      .attr('r','10')
      .attr('stroke','black')
      .attr('stroke-width',1)
      .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.Color1; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

You could just slice the last character off if you have the semicolon hard coded in your data:

```
.attr("fill", function(d) { return d.Color1.slice(0,-1); })
```

Comment: That was it, and your slice solution was better than my thought after reading the first sentence in your response, thank you!